# How to autosize a ModalWindow in wicket which is depend on content

Tags: wicket, modal-window

i am working on modalwindow but it does not autosizes when content of this
     window getting increased
     Also tell how to set scrollbar to Modalwindow if size of
     content is more.
     I want modalwindow autosizable please tell me simple code how to do
     this??
     & what is the actual use of setOutputMarkupId(true)???

```
final ModalWindow modalpostyourView=new ModalWindow("modalpostyourView");
    modalpostyourView.setPageMapName("modalpostyourView-1");
    modalpostyourView.setCookieName("modalpostyourView-1");
    modalpostyourView.setWidthUnit("");

    add(modalpostyourView);
    modalpostyourView.setPageCreator(new ModalWindow.PageCreator() 
    {
        @Override
        public Page createPage() 
        {
            return new UserPost(ForumForm.this,modalpostyourView);
        }
    });
    AjaxLink postyourView=new AjaxLink("postyourView")
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) 
        {
            modalpostyourView.show(target);
        }
    };
    add(postyourView);
```

Comment: how about not starting new questions each day? What about the questions you got answers/comments ? If you not react to people,no one is willing to help you. Also: what have you tried? What did not work? Reading the available JavaDoc should answer some of your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/wiki/ModalX. This project provides extension of ModalWindow that supports that feature.